# What is a good practice nowadays to detect if user reaches my website using Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web-applications, user-agent

I noticed that Internet Explorer is not natively compatible with SSE yet.

In order to fix it (using WebSockets or other workaround), I just want to redirect an IE's user to a page of my application saying:
**"Unfortunately, this website is not (currently) fully compatible with Internet Explorer, please use any other browser"**.

What is a good (best?) practice to detect an IE's user no matter the targeted page of my website is?

I thought of this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
Place content here to target all Internet Explorer users.
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: not compatible even with 10 and 11? 11 is even better than Chrome I think. anyway, look here - http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Great link, will test it :)

Comment: Check the user agent?

Comment: @vsync IE11 is not better than chrome. In almost every way, it is still worse (compare them on the HTML5 test)

Comment: If you want to use only HTML see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, browserstack.com isn't free, but http://browserling.com is. However, not all browsers are available in the free version

Comment: @vsync Even with IE 11, SSE doesn't work.

Comment: Just tested using browserstack.com, no SSE with IE 11 => "EventSource is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to never check for user agents nowadays as they change frequently and are an unreliable and poor fallback approach.

Consider [feature detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh475813.aspx), rather than browser detection. This ensures that your website will function properly even when a new version of the browser is released. It also ensures that any past features that your site uses that wasn't supported in older versions a browser but are now supported in a newer version work without any code changes.